# Clonar tabela com valores do checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, html5

> Codigo atualizado. Ajuda de Edson Alves.

Estou com dificuldades no calculo **Soma total** ao desmarcar o checkbox. No momento em que vou marcando, ele calcula certinho, o problema é na desmarcação que deveria subtrair.

```js
$(".c").click(function() {

  var values = $(this).val().split('|');
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

    var quantity = $("table[id^=tabelaIE]").length;

    $(this).data('qty', quantity);

    var table = $("#tabelaIE").clone(true)
      .attr('id', function() {
        return this.id + quantity;
      })
      .find(':text,:file')
      .attr('id', function() {
        return this.id + quantity;
      })
      .val("")
      .end();
    //Adiciona valores 1|Taxa de locação|+|15.00|FIX|%|POR|VLT
    table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
    table.find('.tDias').text($("#dias").val());
    table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
    tTotal = values[3] * $("#dias").val();
    table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));

    values.forEach(function(valor, index) {
      table.find('[class="split' + (index + 1) + '"]').val(valor)
    });

    table.appendTo('#abc');

    var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
    $('#somaTabelaIE').val(eval(oldVal || 0) + eval(tTotal))
  } else {
    var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
    $('#somaTabelaIE').val(oldVal - eval(tTotal))
    //remove a table que pertence ao checkbox
    $("table#tabelaIE" + $(this).data('qty')).remove()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="dias" value="2">

<div id="abc">
  <div id="abc">
    <table id="tabelaIE" width='400' border='0'>
      <tr>
        <td class="tNome" width='164'></td>
        <td class="tDias" width='36' align='right'></td>
        <td class="tValor" width='53' align='right'></td>
        <td class="tTotal" width='119' align='right'></td>
        <td class="tValores">
          <input type="hidden" class="split1" value="">
          <input type="hidden" class="split2" value="">
          <input type="hidden" class="split3" value="">
          <input type="hidden" class="split4" value="">
          <input type="hidden" class="split5" value="">
          <input type="hidden" class="split6" value="">
          <input type="hidden" class="split7" value="">
          <input type="hidden" class="split8" value="">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    Soma Total: <input type="text" name="somaTabelaIE" id="somaTabelaIE" value="">
  </div>
</div>


<fieldset class="scheduler-border">
 <legend class="scheduler-border">Impostos/Encargos</legend>
 
 <div id="D1">1. 
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c obrigatorio" type="checkbox" value="1|Texto 1|+|15.00|FIX|%|POR|VLT" alt="+ 0.15 FIX %" title="Texto 1"> <b> Texto 1 </b>
  <input type="text" value="" class="i"> 
 </div>

 <div id="D2">2. 
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" value="2|Texto 2|+|5.00|DIA||MON|DIA" alt="+ 5.00 DIA " title="Texto 2"> Texto 2
  <input type="text" value="" class="i">
 </div>
  
 <div id="D3">3. 
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" value="3|Texto 3|+|30.00|FIX||MON|VLT" alt="+ 30.00 FIX " title="Texto 3"> Texto 3
  <input type="text" value="" class="i">
 </div>
  
 <div id="D4">4. 
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" value="3|Texto 4|+|35,00|FIX||MON|VLT" alt="+ 35,00 FIX " title="Texto 4"> Texto 4
  <input type="text" value="" class="i">
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara, mas se deseja apenas clonar vc pode usar o clone do jQuery: `$('.checkbox').clone(true)`. O true indica que vc quer clonar junto com seus valores

Comment: @edsonalves editei meu codigo, não estou sabendo apagar a tabela criada ao desmarcar o checkbox. Sabe como fazer?

Comment: você pode usar a função `prop` pra determinar se o checkbox ta checkado ao clicar: `$(this).prop('checked')` e decidir se remove ou adiciona

Comment: Seu novo problema é que quando vc entra no `else` o valor `tTotal` não existe. Você pode copiar a linha `tTotal = values[3] * $("#dias").val();` pra dentro do `else` ou jogar ela pra antes do `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que finalmente entendi sua pergunta, seguem modificações:

```js
  $(".c").click(function(){
     var values = $(this).val().split('|');
        //define se esta marcado ou não
        if($(this).prop('checked')){

           var quantity = $("table[id^=tabelaIE]").length;

           //adiciona o valor para identificar na hora de remover
           $(this).data( 'qty', quantity );

           // Clone the main table
           var table = $("#tabelaIE").clone(true)
           // Change its ID to the current ID plus the quantity variable
           .attr( 'id', function() { return this.id + quantity; })
           // find any text or file inputs
           .find( ':text,:file' )
           // change their IDs
           .attr( 'id', function() { return this.id + quantity; })
           // set the input values to ""
           .val( "" )
           // return to the cloned table
           .end();
           //adiciona valores ao texto dos td
           table.find('.nome').text(values[1]);
           table.find('.dias').text(values[2]);
           table.find('.valor').text(values[3]);
           table.find('.total').text((values[0]) * (values[3]));
           
           //adiciona valores nos inputs em suas posições
           values.forEach(function(valor, index){
            table.find('[class="split'+(index+1)+'"]').val(valor)
           });
           
           
           // append wherever you want it.
           // As the comment below your question states,
           //   this is not a valid placement
           table.appendTo('#abc');
           var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
           $('#somaTabelaIE').val(eval(oldVal||0) + eval(values[3]))
        }else{
           var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
           $('#somaTabelaIE').val(oldVal - eval(values[3]))
           //remove a table que pertence ao checkbox
           $("table#tabelaIE"+$(this).data('qty')).remove()
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">
 <table id="tabelaIE" width='400' border='0'>
  <tr>
    <td class="nome" width='164'>Nome</td>
    <td class="dias" width='36' align='right'>2</td>
    <td class="valor" width='53' align='right'>60.00</td>
    <td class="total" width='119' align='right'>120.00 <input type="text" name="opcoe[]" value="" style="width: 50px"></td>
      <td class="valores"> 
      <input type="text" class="split1" value="">
      <input type="text" class="split2" value="">
      <input type="text" class="split3" value="">
      <input type="text" class="split4" value="">
      <input type="text" class="split5" value="">
      <input type="text" class="split6" value="">
      <input type="text" class="split7" value="">
      <input type="text" class="split8" value=""></td>
  </tr>
     
 </table>

 <input type="text" name="somaTabelaIE" id="somaTabelaIE" value="">
</div>


<fieldset class="scheduler-border">
 <legend class="scheduler-border">Impostos/Encargos</legend>
 
 <div id="D1">1. 
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c obrigatorio" type="checkbox" value="1|Texto 1|+|15.00|FIX|%|POR|VLT|1" alt="+ 0.15 FIX %" title="Texto 1"> <b> Texto 1 </b>
  <input type="text" value="" class="i"> 
 </div>

 <div id="D2">2. 
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" value="2|Texto 2|+|5.00|DIA||MON|DIA" alt="+ 5.00 DIA " title="Texto 2"> Texto 2
  <input type="text" value="" class="i">
 </div>
  
 <div id="D3">3. 
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" value="3|Texto 3|+|30.00|FIX||MON|VLT" alt="+ 30.00 FIX " title="Texto 3"> Texto 3
  <input type="text" value="" class="i">
 </div>
  
 <div id="D4">4. 
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" value="3|Texto 4|+|35,00|FIX||MON|VLT" alt="+ 35,00 FIX " title="Texto 4"> Texto 4
  <input type="text" value="" class="i">
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

Disponivel também no fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kndh7xw5/1/

Comment: E a parte do valor e soma total, como faz para incluir na tabela?

Comment: De onde o valor a ser somado deveria ser pego?

Comment: Cada checkbox, dentro do campo value, esta assim `1|Texto 1|+|15.00|FIX|%|POR|VLT`, preciso pegar cada campo desse separado pelo pippe, colocar na tabela criada, e tambem pegar todos os dados separados e colocar em um input oculto, para fazer a montagem dos calculos e enviar ao BD.

Comment: com `$('input').val().split('|')` vc obtem uma array com esses valores... Mas nao entendi o que quis dizer com "a soma" qual dos valores deveria ser somado?

Comment: Vou explicar...

Comment: Na sequencia de pippe, fica assim: `ID | Nome da Taxa | fator | valor | ...`, já existe uma variavel que tem os dias contratado que deve ser multiplicado pelo valor `$("#dias").val()`. No inicio da tabela eu deixei ela preenchida com um valor de exemplo.

Comment: veja essa imagem para ver como ficaria http://prntscr.com/lmln4c

Comment: Modifiquei o código pegando a posição 3 e somando, depois subtraindo ao remover... Seu primeiro input tava sem ID, então adicionei 1 pra não dar erro. Ve se era isso que vc precisava pq ainda acho que nao entendi bem.

Comment: Vou testar.....

Comment: Atualizei meu codigo, de uma olhada na parte da tabela, coloquei IDs e novos campos. Acho que assim fica melhor para entender.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86195/discussion-between-tiago-and-edson-alves).

Comment: Bom dia Edison, atualizei o código original, estou com dificuldades o calculo soma total. O que esta errado?